# Базовая аутентификация в HTTP запросе

Tags: php, api

Как мне сделать базовую аутентификацию в HTTP запросе для работы с API TrageOgre?
[Вот ссылка (раздел Private API).](https://tradeogre.com/help/api)

Возможно ли реализовать это без сторонних библиотек на чистом PHP?

Comment: `https://login:pass@example.com/`

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!